# <li> elements lose desired alignment when text in one of them overflows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create an ingredients list, where I'm using the `ul` and `li` elements with `div`s inside of each `li` element for each different information type (amount, description or price). In the third `li` element, the description is too long to fit in the normal space of its own div. This causes it to overflow downwards (not to the right). This is fine, but the probem is that the next `li` element starts in the wrong place because of this overflow. I've marked the text that is rendered in the wrong place.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        thawed puff pastry sheet
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        2 USD
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        ~
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        All-purpose flour, for rolling
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        5 USD
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        round brie cheese (8 to 12 ounces, 5- to 7-inch diameter)
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        10 USD
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        1
        <!--- WRONG PLACE. Should start on new row -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        Large egg, beaten
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        1 USD
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        ~
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        Baguette slices or crackes, to serve
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        1 USD
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What can I do to make each `li` element start on a new row, even if the element above overflowed?

Comment: You got to start by putting the col elements into _rows_, that’s the very basic of how the grid system works.

Comment: @BramVanroy: The Bootstrap CSS isn't included properly in the snippet you created

Comment: Fixed. In the future, please use the snippets rather than external services. Also note that you are using an old version of bootstrap.

Comment: @Sahand Don't delete questions, just self-answer. It'll be closed as a typo, but still available as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `float:left` in the `col-*` classes. To fix this use `.row` class in the `<li>`

Also no need to use same `sm`, `md`, `lg` values..Just use `xs` here if you want same grid structure for all screen...

...or use only `sm` if you want same grid structure till `sm` breakpoint

***Stack Snippet***

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="container-fluid">
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      thawed puff pastry sheet
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      2 USD
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      ~
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      All-purpose flour, for rolling
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      5 USD
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      round brie cheese (8 to 12 ounces, 5- to 7-inch diameter)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      10 USD
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      Large egg, beaten
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      1 USD
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      ~
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      Baguette slices or crackes, to serve
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      1 USD
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: we need also container .. not only row

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah...Updated...

Answer (score 3):

Add `row` class to your

items.

```
<li class="row">...</li>
```

Comment: unfortunately not only this .. he need also container, etc